# How to build nginx test environment?

Tags: linux, nginx

I'm a beginner of nginx. I wonder how to build nginx test environment~? How do you know your nginx configuration is workable or non-workable?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use -t parameter to test without executing it.

> sudo ./nginx -t

It should either print that the syntax is OK and the test is successful or the test has failed and shows the error.

For me for a successful test I get below:

*nginx: the configuration file /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf syntax is ok*

But for a bad syntax I get this

*nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "https" in /usr/local/openresty/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:12*

But normally I just simply restart nginx and if there's an error I get it on the command line, then use journalctl to view the details.